# I can't use a .xml file that place in drawable folder, for my app's background

Tags: java, android, xml, drawable

I want to design an Info Form in my application, but when I'm using of my custom background, app crashed. somebody can help me to resolve it.

This is my .xml codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/main_activity_background" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/edittext_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
       </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_color"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/devide_line" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is codes' of `XML` file related to drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <shape>

            <gradient

                android:endColor="#FAEBD7"
                android:angle="180"
                android:type="radial"/>

            <corners
                android:radius="300dp" />

        </shape>

    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Use Logcat and examine the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Share the crash logs here

Comment: this is logcat Error : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.forminfo/com.example.forminfo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your drawable xml code in `<layer-list>` tag

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <item>
    
        <shape>
    
            <gradient
    
                android:endColor="#FAEBD7"
                android:angle="180"
                android:type="radial"
    
                />
    
            <corners
    
                android:radius="300dp"
    
                />
    
        </shape>
    
    </item>

<layer-list>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. logcat Error is "inflating class android.widget.relativelayout"

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one item in drawable xml then you can use directly `<shape>`tag in drawable file like below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#FAEBD7"
        android:angle="180"
        android:type="radial"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="300dp" />
</shape>
```

`<layer-list>` is a drawable object that manages arrays of other drawable objects in the specific order, For example:

```
<layer-list>
 <item>
  <shape/>
 </item>
 <item>
  <shape/>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

For more info regarding drawable resources you can check this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource)